Issues with vxgi implementation when rotating the camera
right now I have implemented vxgi algorithm. Voxelization is working fine, same for mipmap generation. But, I have an issue when I rotate the camera. Basically, it is not stable when it is rotated. I don't know, what the issue could be, but I thought it might be because I am recovering world space vertex position from depth buffer.
So, this is how it is looking in one camera position (lets say initial):

And this is how it looks when camera is a little bit rotated:

And this is the code for tracing cones(passing everything in world position to it):
vec4 ConeTrace(vec3 Coord, vec3 Direction, vec3 Normal)
{
    float Angle = Pi / 3.0;
    float Aperture = tan(Angle / 2.0);
    float Distance = 0.01;
    vec3  AccumColor = vec3(0);
    float AccumOcclusion = 0.0;

    vec3 StartPos   = (Coord) * VoxelSceneSize;
    while(Distance <= 1.0 && AccumOcclusion < 1.0)
    {
        vec3 ConePos = StartPos + Direction * Distance * VoxelSceneSize;

        float Diameter = 2.0 * Aperture * Distance;
        float Mip = log2(Distance * VoxelSceneSize.x);
        vec4 VoxelSample = textureLod(VoxelGrid, ConePos * 0.5 + 0.5, Mip);

        AccumColor += (1.0 - AccumOcclusion) * VoxelSample.rgb;
        AccumOcclusion += (1.0 - AccumOcclusion) * VoxelSample.a;

        Distance += Diameter;
    }

    AccumOcclusion = min(AccumOcclusion, 1.0);
    return vec4(AccumColor, AccumOcclusion);
}

The main issue might be in this function as well, but I can't see it myself. Don't know if there is enough information about this issue, but, anyway, I would be thankfull any help I could get, thanks in advance
